# Large Local Contents on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

Everyone.
I'm in trouble about loading local contents on UIWebView.

I made MediaViewer with UIWebView.
When the UIWebView open large ***local*** contents (about 600KB Html with 30MB images),
the application crushed in the middle of loading.(It takes 3 sec)

I also tried loading same contents via online, it succeeded normaly.
(Mobile Safari can load with out any problems too.)

Does anyone know the solution how to load big local contents with UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is not meant to be used like this and even Apple's engineers admit that it is a memory hog. You should create a viewer to fit your own purposes instead of trying to show a large document.

Mobile Safari has several optimizations in place (like the new Nitro Javascript engine) that allow it to display a much greater range of items than UIWebView.